# Xcode assets Contents.json is not updated in SourceTree

Tags: xcode, git, image, assets, atlassian-sourcetree

When I edit my assets catalog by adding or editing an image the Contents.json file does not show up in SourceTree if I want to commit the changes.
The edited or added image shows in SourceTree but no changes to Contents.json.

I restarted my Mac, cleaned the build folder. It still does not show up.
I check `.gitignore` but it does not contain "Contents.json".
I also tried `git status --ignored` but it does not list "Contents.json".
`git status --ignored` lists the following files in the `Assets` folder:

```
    ABCland/Resources/Company/Assets/.DS_Store
    ABCland/Resources/Company/Assets/BBM.xcassets/ALT_BBM_SS/.DS_Store
    ABCland/Resources/Company/Assets/JM.xcassets/.DS_Store
    ABCland/Resources/Company/Assets/SN.xcassets/.DS_Store
    ABCland/Resources/Company/Assets/SOL.xcassets/.DS_Store
    ABCland/Resources/Company/Assets/STB.xcassets/.DS_Store
```

Could it be because of the .DS_Store files?

Answer (score 1):

I opened the **Settings** in SourceTree and selected the **Git** tab and looked up the **Global Ignore List** path to the `.gitignore_global` file.
I looked into the content of `.gitignore_global` and saw that "Contents.json" was in there.

```
maxhuber@Max-MacBook-Pro ios-app % cat /Users/maxhuber/.gitignore_global
*~
.DS_Store
Contents.json
play-pause-blue.png
play-pause-blue@2x.png
play-pause-blue@3x.png
```

I solved it by removing "Contents.json" from `.gitignore_global`. It works now!